# Multiple div hide/show conflict with each other

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css

here I added multiple div's with a different id when I click then the other div is displayed none here I'm trying to achieve other div's will not conflict with each other. Can anyone suggest what might be the issue.

```js
var divs = ["on1", "off1", "on2", "off2", "on3", "off3"];
var visibleDivId = null;

function divVisibility(divId) {
  if (visibleDivId === divId) {
    visibleDivId = null;
  } else {
    visibleDivId = divId;
    hideNonVisibleDivs();
  }

}

function hideNonVisibleDivs() {
  var i, divId, div;
  for (i = 0; i < divs.length; i++) {
    divId = divs[i];
    div = document.getElementById(divId);
    if (visibleDivId === divId) {
      div.style.display = "block";
    } else {
      div.style.display = "none";
    }
  }
}
```

```css
.buttons a {
  font-size: 16px;
}

.buttons a:hover {
  cursor: pointer;
  font-size: 16px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="main_div">
  <div class="buttons">
    <a href="#" onclick="divVisibility('on1');">On</a> |
    <a href="#" onclick="divVisibility('off1');">Off</a> |
  </div>
  <div class="inner_div">
    <div id="on1">I'm Div One</div>
    <div id="off1" style="display: none;">I'm Div Two</div>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="main_div">
  <div class="buttons">
    <a href="#" onclick="divVisibility('on2');">On</a> |
    <a href="#" onclick="divVisibility('off2');">Off</a> |
  </div>
  <div class="inner_div">
    <div id="on2">I'm Div One</div>
    <div id="off2" style="display: none;">I'm Div Two</div>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="main_div">
  <div class="buttons">
    <a href="#" onclick="divVisibility('on3');">On</a> |
    <a href="#" onclick="divVisibility('off3');">Off</a> |
  </div>
  <div class="inner_div">
    <div id="on3">I'm Div One</div>
    <div id="off3" style="display: none;">I'm Div Two</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I hope I undestand your problem correctly. Is this the logic you want?

I have tried to adjust your code but I find the HTML markup and your solution logic a bit too complicated and unflexible. You would not be able to add new `main_div` without registering them in the array.

I have re-written it completely.

```js
allOnOffButtons = document.querySelectorAll("a");

allOnOffButtons.forEach(button=>{
  button.addEventListener('click', handleVisibility);
})

function handleVisibility(e) { 
  // check if the button was on or off
  const clickedButtonClass = e.srcElement.className;
  
  // grab the inner div that belongs to the clicked button
  const clickedinnerDiv = e.srcElement.closest(".main_div").querySelector(".inner_div");
 
  // find all divs inside the given inner_div
  const allDivsInsideInnerDiv = clickedinnerDiv.querySelectorAll("div");

  // check if they should be shown or hidden
  allDivsInsideInnerDiv.forEach(div => {
    if (div.className === clickedButtonClass) {
       div.style.display = "block";
    } else {
       div.style.display = "none";
    }
  })
}
```

```css
.buttons a {
  font-size: 16px;
}

.buttons a:hover {
  cursor: pointer;
  font-size: 16px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="main_div">
  <div class="buttons">
    <a href="#" class="on">On</a> |
    <a href="#" class="off">Off</a> |
  </div>
  <div class="inner_div">
    <div class="on">I'm Div One (on)</div>
    <div class="off" style="display: none;">I'm Div Two (off)</div>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="main_div">
  <div class="buttons">
    <a href="#" class="on">On</a> |
    <a href="#" class="off">Off</a> |
  </div>
  <div class="inner_div">
    <div class="on">I'm Div One (on)</div>
    <div class="off" style="display: none;">I'm Div Two (off)</div>
  </div>
  
</div>

<div class="main_div">
  <div class="buttons">
    <a href="#" class="on">On</a> |
    <a href="#" class="off">Off</a> |
  </div>
  <div class="inner_div">
    <div class="on">I'm Div One (on)</div>
    <div class="off" style="display: none;">I'm Div Two (off)</div>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="main_div">
  <div class="buttons">
    <a href="#" class="on">On</a> |
    <a href="#" class="off">Off</a> |
  </div>
  <div class="inner_div">
    <div class="on">I'm Div One (on)</div>
    <div class="off" style="display: none;">I'm Div Two (off)</div>
  </div>
</div>


<div class="main_div">
  <div class="buttons">
    <a href="#" class="on">On</a> |
    <a href="#" class="off">Off</a> |
  </div>
  <div class="inner_div">
    <div class="on">I'm Div One (on)</div>
    <div class="off" style="display: none;">I'm Div Two (off)</div>
  </div>
</div>


<div class="main_div">
  <div class="buttons">
    <a href="#" class="on">On</a> |
    <a href="#" class="off">Off</a> |
  </div>
  <div class="inner_div">
    <div class="on">I'm Div One (on)</div>
    <div class="off" style="display: none;">I'm Div Two (off)</div>
  </div>
</div>


<div class="main_div">
  <div class="buttons">
    <a href="#" class="on">On</a> |
    <a href="#" class="off">Off</a> |
  </div>
  <div class="inner_div">
    <div class="on">I'm Div One (on)</div>
    <div class="off" style="display: none;">I'm Div Two (off)</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Yes it is the same as what I'm to trying to achieve. The same logic i applied here https://jsfiddle.net/MehrajKhan/td0oqz7n/ not working.

Comment: Well that is a different example, isn't it? Would something like this work? https://jsfiddle.net/74uxco5e/ Try using console.log() to debug your code.